# Layout bug with my templates

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, template-engine, python-2.7

On all my template rendering for a particular app, the output ends with `None`:

```
...</html>None
```

This must be a bug and probably in my code and I've spent days trying to track it down. There's nothing special about my app and this bug appears on every page I use template rendering, whether I use a seperate template engine or not. There is nothing special about my code:

```
    class Objectives(NewBaseHandler):

        @user_required
        def get(self):
            user = auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id']))
            if user:
                self.render_template('objectives.html', {'user': user})
            else:

                self.render_template('/', {})

class NewBaseHandler(BaseHandler):

    """
........BaseHandler for all requests

........Holds the auth and session properties so they are reachable for all requests
...."""

    def dispatch(self):
        """
............Save the sessions for preservation across requests
........"""

        # self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        # if self.request.host.find('localhost') > 0:  # for a Swedish domain that uses Swedish
        # or lang = os.environ.get("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")

        i18n.get_i18n().set_locale('sv')
        lang_code_get = self.request.get('hl', None)
        if lang_code_get:
           #self.session['i18n_language'] = lang_code_get
           i18n.get_i18n().set_locale(lang_code_get)
        try:
            response = super(NewBaseHandler, self).dispatch()
            self.response.write(response)
        finally:
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def auth(self):
        return auth.get_auth()

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session_store(self):
        return sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def auth_config(self):
        """
............Dict to hold urls for login/logout
........"""

        return {'login_url': self.uri_for('login'),
                'logout_url': self.uri_for('logout')}

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(self, file, template_args):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates',
                            file)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_args))

    def render_jinja(self, filename, **template_args):
        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename,
                            **template_args))
```

How can I check where the output `None` is coming from? It's probably not coming from the template and it doesn't seem to be coming from the handlers and there is no other code.

Thank you

Comment: Try changing `self.render_template('/', {})` to `self.render_template('/', {'user':user})` and see if it still appends None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Objectives.get()` you must return a value. Since you don't do this Python assumes the result is `None`. This value you get in `NewBaseHandler.dispatch()` when calling to base `dispatch` implementation and then write it to response.

If I get your app correctly returning empty string in `get` method will solve the problem.

Comment: It works to return empty string. I think I must learn what the dispatch function does since I just tooke it from somewhere. Thanks a lot for saving me valuable time with the workaround.